# can't deploy heroku with mern +graphql

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a full stack web application with MERN + GRAPH QL, but when deployed to heroku
GET query missing.

It is displayed and does not go well.

The log at deploy is here

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
NODE_ENV=production
NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
engines.node (package.json):  v10.15.3
engines.npm (package.json):   v6.4.1
engines.yarn (package.json):  v1.15.2

Resolving node version v10.15.3...
Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
Bootstrapping npm v6.4.1 (replacing 6.4.1)...
npm v6.4.1 installed
Resolving yarn version v1.15.2...
Downloading and installing yarn (1.15.2)...
Installed yarn 1.15.2

-----> Restoring cache

node_modules
-----> Installing dependencies
Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
yarn install v1.15.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.62s.

-----> Build
Running heroku-postbuild (yarn)
yarn run v1.15.2
$ NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client

core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_d5c70a66310676d67abc805c1a172941/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

core-js-pure@3.1.3 postinstall /tmp/build_d5c70a66310676d67abc805c1a172941/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

added 1464 packages from 846 contributors and audited 889284 packages in 56.855s
found 0 vulnerabilities

client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_d5c70a66310676d67abc805c1a172941/client
react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/components/Habits/MyHabits.js
Line 17:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'currentUser' and 'history'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/Habits/StarButton.js
Line 19:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'currentUser' and 'habit._id'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/components/Habits/StarLabel.js
Line 20:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'currentUser' and 'habit._id'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

257.66 KB  build/static/js/2.8fc707a7.chunk.js
97.2 KB    build/static/css/2.621b5bde.chunk.css
9.7 KB     build/static/js/main.d52bf224.chunk.js
886 B      build/static/css/main.15b794e3.chunk.css
762 B      build/static/js/runtime~main.a8a9905a.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:

"homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

yarn global add serve
serve -s build

Find out more about deployment here:




Done in 135.78s.

-----> Caching build

node_modules
-----> Pruning devDependencies
yarn install v1.15.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > react-infinite-scroller@1.2.4" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning " > react-spinners@0.5.4" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.0.0".
warning " > react-spinners@0.5.4" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.0.0".
warning "react-spinners > @emotion/core@10.0.10" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=16.3.0".
warning "react-spinners > recompose@0.30.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
Done in 24.36s.

-----> Build succeeded!
!     Unmet dependencies don't fail yarn install but may cause runtime issues
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
-----> Discovering process types
Procfile declares types     -> (none)
Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
Done: 71.8M
-----> Launching...
Released v34
https://manehabi.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

package.json is here. It is placed directly under the root. Similarly, it is as below server.js directly below.

```
{
"name": "manehabi",
"scripts": {
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client \"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
},
"engines": {
"node": "v10.15.3",
"npm": "v6.4.1",
"yarn": "v1.15.2"
},
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "server.js",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"apollo-server": "^2.5.0",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.17.0",
"graphql": "^14.3.1",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"md5": "^2.2.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"mongoose": "^5.5.11",
"react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
"react-spinners": "^0.5.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^4.1.0",
"nodemon": "^1.19.0"
}
}
const express = require("express");
const { ApolloServer } = require("apollo-server");
const typeDefs = require("./typeDefs.graphql");
const resolvers = require("./resolvers");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());

const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;
const secret = require("./config/keys").secret;

mongoose
.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: async ({ req }) => {
        let token = null;
        let currentUser = null;

        try {
            token = req.headers["authorization"];
             if (token) {
                 currentUser = await jwt.verify(token, secret);
                 }
        } catch (err) {
             console.error(Unable to authenticate user with token);
        }
          return { currentUser };
    }

});

 // Server static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
// Set static folder

app.use(express.static("client/build"));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
console.log("hi there");
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

}

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

server.listen({ port }).then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(  Server ready at ${url});
});
```

The client folder is created in the same hierarchy.

Even if you look at git log, server seems to be working properly, so I think that getting the index.html of react is not well done.

Answer (score 0):

hi can you try with this

```
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen({ port }, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${port}${server.graphqlPath}`);
  console.log(` Subscriptions ready at ${port}${server.subscriptionsPath}`);
});
```

Comment: maybe try to serve the client just witth express then add apollo server because this piece of code
server.listen({ port }).then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(  Server ready at ${url});
});

creates graphql instance on / 
with the one i sent you the enpoint is /graphql